# Heroku , How to know ruby version of project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

In Heroku, I have been added as a collaborator of a project. I need to get that project in my local. And for that I need to know which Ruby version project has. Rails version of project is `3.1` I knew this via the `Gemfile` file.

Please suggest what should I do for that?

Comment: Have you been added as colaborator in heroku via git?

Comment: If you're on cedar you can also control the version of ruby you're using: http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2012/5/9/multiple_ruby_version_support_on_heroku/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can know it by the stack use on this project.

```
heroku stack
```

If it's not Cedar stack you can have information about ruby version is used on heroku

Exemple of output

```
$ heroku stack                                                                                                                                                            
  aspen-mri-1.8.6
* bamboo-mri-1.9.2
  bamboo-ree-1.8.7
  cedar (beta)
```

The * represent the stack use on this project and the version is define.

```
aspen-mri-1.8.6 => MRI 1.8.6
bamboo-mri-1.9.2 => MRI 1.9.2
bamboo-ree-1.8.7 => REE 1.8.7
```

In case of the stack is cedar. By default the ruby version is 1.9.2 MRI. If it's change by ruby 1.9.3, It's a trick define by config. You can have information by

```
heroku config
```

You can have `RUBY_VERSION          => ruby-1.9.3-p0` define if the ruby 1.9.3-p0 is used.

Comment: the question can be obscure if you are not a real good user of heroku and Heroku is mention only on title not in text. The misunderstanding can be easy.

Comment: Hi, please note though that 'RUBY_VERSION' isn't a supported heroku feature, and is likely to stop working at some point.

Comment: It seems that for the Cedar stack, this does not work. Use `heroku run ruby -v`.

Answer (score 31):

For anyone looking for this, it is straightforward to get the info with

`heroku run ruby -v`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the answer today